# How to compare startdate / enddate with actualdate in my query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I would be happy, if someone could give me a hint.

I have the following query in which I calculate the avarage salary of an empoyee depending how long he works for a company.

```
Declare @data table
              (Employee_Number int, 
               StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, 
               Salary bigint)

Insert into @data(Employee_Number, StartDate, EndDate, Salary) 
values (4711, '20160201', '20160213', 4000), 
   (4712, '20160201', '20160309', 8000);

with inc(n) as
( 
    Select 
        7 * (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1)) -1)
    From 
        (Select 1 
         From (values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
         Cross Join (values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
    ) x(n)
 )
Select 
    Employee_Number,
    Weeks = case when DATEADD(DAY, i.n, StartDate) <= EndDate then DATEADD(DAY, i.n, StartDate) else EndDate end,
    Avg = Salary / (CEILING(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate) as numeric(9, 1)) / 7) + 1)
From @data d
Inner Join inc i on i.n < ((DATEDIFF(DAY, StartDate, EndDate))) + 7
Order By Employee_Number, Weeks
```

So the logic and everything I want is correct. But now I want to add something. With `getdate()` I mean the actual date today (dynamicly).

1. I would like first to check if the `getdate() > enddate`. If yes -> than put all the salary in one row without calculating the avarage salary.
2. Second, i want to check if `getdate()  < startdate`. If yes -> use startdate. If not -> use getdate() instead of startdate.

I would be so thankful if you can help me out how I can manage that because I have no clue.

Thank you guys,
Jinks

---

EDIT: examples:

current result with the query above:

```
Employee_Number Weeks   Avg
4711    2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 1333.3333333333333333
4711    2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 1333.3333333333333333
4711    2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 1333.3333333333333333

4712    2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-15 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-22 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-29 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-03-07 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-03-09 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
```

With the new logic:

1)
I would like first to check if the getdate() > enddate. If yes -> than put all the salary in one row without calculating the avarage salary. So if getdate() is > enddate than use enddate.
result:

```
Employee_Number Weeks   Avg
4711    2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 4000.0000000000000000
4712    2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-15 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-22 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-02-29 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-03-07 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
4712    2016-03-09 00:00:00.000 1142.8571428571428571
```

2) Second, i want to check if getdate() < startdate. If yes -> use startdate. If not -> use getdate() instead of startdate.
result:

```
Employee_Number Weeks   Avg
4711    2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 4000.0000000000000000
4712    2016-02-11 00:00:00.000 1600.0000000000000000
4712    2016-02-18 00:00:00.000 1600.0000000000000000
4712    2016-02-25 00:00:00.000 1600.0000000000000000
4712    2016-03-03 00:00:00.000 1600.0000000000000000
4712    2016-03-09 00:00:00.000 1600.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Posting some sample data and desired output would help greatly. Maybe go to sqlfiddle.com and create the tables.

Comment: I've edited my comment. I hope now it is clearer what I mean : )

Comment: Posting some sample data and desired output would help greatly. Maybe go to sqlfiddle.com and create the tables.

Comment: One piece at a time you are getting there. Maybe go to sqlfiddle.com and create the tables.

Comment: There is already example Data in the code. I also gave you example results in the first post/edit section

Comment: `getdate()  < startdate` that mean the future? Are you measuring the wage for someone not even earned one?

Comment: Ahh I see you have a table variable with a couple rows of data in it. Not sure I totally understand the logic here but give me minute.

Comment: I just don't get the logic of how you get your desired output. I am missing some detail somewhere.

Comment: @jean: yes I mean the future. if getdate() < startdate then I need to use startdate as the starting date.

Comment: @Sean Lange: I just changed the date values to visualize you what my desired result would look like if I use logic 1) and logic 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not totally sure what you are trying to do here but pretty sure this is it. This is not quite the exact output you stated but not sure what the rules are for the dates changing and such.

```
Declare @data table
              (Employee_Number int, 
               StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, 
               Salary bigint)

Insert into @data(Employee_Number, StartDate, EndDate, Salary) 
values (4711, '20160201', '20160213', 4000), 
   (4712, '20160201', '20160309', 8000);

with inc(n) as
( 
    Select 
        7 * (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1)) -1)
    From 
        (Select 1 
         From (values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
         Cross Join (values (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
    ) x(n)
 )
Select 
    Employee_Number,
    Weeks = case when DATEADD(DAY, i.n, case when getdate() < StartDate then StartDate else getdate() end) <= EndDate then DATEADD(DAY, i.n, case when getdate() < StartDate then StartDate else getdate() end) else EndDate end,
    Avg = Salary / (CEILING(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, case when getdate() < StartDate then StartDate else getdate() end, EndDate) as numeric(9, 1)) / 7) + 1)
From 
@data d
Inner Join inc i on i.n < ((DATEDIFF(DAY, case when getdate() < StartDate then StartDate else getdate() end, EndDate))) + 7
Order By Employee_Number, Weeks
```

Comment: Buddy, I love you! : )

That is exactly what I've needed. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You are quite welcome. Sorry for the confusion earlier. :)

Comment: Care to share the problem? It is much easier to help if you explain what is wrong.

Comment: Sean, the post was to long, so I could not post my whole code and the results. so thats why I've created a new Thread...also because now it is a different problem then I had before. Dont to wanted to trick anyone!

Here is the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367370/problems-with-startdate-and-enddate-in-my-query-dont-get-the-results-i-want